# Server boot when AC power connected

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I've been using an old notebook as a personal server for a few months now, but I have a problem. The battery of the laptop does not work anymore, so it's always plugged in, but it's quite irritating having to turn on the laptop manually by pressing the power on button on the notebook every time it looses power.

I want it to boot automatically as soon as it's plugged in.

Now I know that there is a bios option for that, but I looked it up and my Bios unfortunately doesn't support that option, is there a different way that my laptop will boot up as soon it's plugged in ?

I heard that one can flash its own BIOS on the system, but that is usually not recommended.

I'm using a 'Compaq 15-H093NG', and it's running Ubuntu Server 22.04.

Comment: If the system hardware doesn't support it, then it doesn't. Of course there may be some hacked BIOSes, but those can as easily hack your laptop to be used for some nefarious purpose if not brick it completely. Look for a cheapo UPS.

Comment: It's an option I'd expect on a desktop, not laptop. It makes little sense on a laptop with two independent power sources.

Comment: Why don't you replace the battery? [High Quality Compaq 15-H093NG Replacement Battery | Laptop Battery Direct](https://www.laptopbatterydirect.net/hp/compaq-15-h093ng-battery.htm) - $36.80

Comment: Have you considered getting a UPS for the laptop? That should solve the stated problem but buying a battery is likely cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop has a non-user serviceable battery, then just removing the battery may be enough. By "non-user serviceable" I mean models where you can't just detach the battery or remove it by undoing a couple screws, but have to disassemble half of the laptop. These models will sometimes boot as soon as the power adapter is connected if the battery is missing.